# Need Help Making a Calculator That Can Perform Multiple Operations

Tags: java, calculator

I have noticed this question asked before, a handful of time, however I cannot seem to find any that really help me at all. I'm currently trying to get my calculator to perform add, subtract, multiply, and divide but am unable to figure out how to get the different operations to perform.

EDIT: I have figured out how to do this for each operation EXCEPT for the add operation. For some reason, I am getting an error that reads "cannot convert from Add to BinaryOperator". The code for add is the same as the other operators, I don't understand why only this operator is triggering an error.

```
package part2.code;

import part1.operations.Add;
import part2.user_interface.CalculatorUI;
import part2.operations.Sub;
import part2.operations.Multiply;
import part2.operations.Divide;
import part2.operations.BinaryOperation;

public class Calculator {


// The current value of the calculator
    private int _value;
    private int _left;
    private int _right;
    private BinaryOperation _op;
    private Add _aop;
    private Sub _sop;
    private Multiply _mop;
    private Divide _dop;


// The user interface via which a user interacts 
    private CalculatorUI _ui;

public Calculator(CalculatorUI calculatorUI) {
        _ui = calculatorUI;
        _value = 0;
        _left = 0;
        _right = 0;
        _aop = new Add();
        _sop = new Sub();
        _mop = new Multiply();
        _dop = new Divide();
    }

public void digitKeyPressed(int d) {
        _value = _value * 10 + d;
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

 public void clearKeyPressed() {
            _value = 0;
            _ui.updateDisplay();
        }

public void addKeyPressed() {
        _left = _value;
        _value = 0;
        _op = _aop;
    }

public void subtractKeyPressed() {
        _left = _value;
        _value = 0;
        _op = _sop;
    }

public void multiplyKeyPressed() {
        _left = _value;
        _value = 0;
        _op = _mop;
    }

public void divideKeyPressed() {
        _left = _value;
        _value = 0;
        _op = _dop;
    }

public void equalKeyPressed() {
        _right = _value;
        _value = _op.perform(_left,_right);
        _ui.updateDisplay();
    }

public int getValue() {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

That is the code for the calculator, accompanying that I have files for each operation that look like this:

```
package part2.operations;

public class Sub implements BinaryOperation {
    public Sub() {}

    @Override
    public int perform(int left, int right) {
            return left - right;
    }
}
```

Replacing "Sub" with whichever operation and the return statement with the corresponding symbol for the operation. There is also a file for BinaryOperation:

```
package part2.operations;

public interface BinaryOperation {
    public int perform(int left, int arg);
}
```

Comment: Map each operator to it's according stringrepresentation and simply retrieve accordingly

Comment: Example: in `subtractKeyPressed`, set `_operation` equal to a `Sub` object. Then when equal is pressed, it uses `Sub` as the operation.

Comment: I've updated my code with changes. As I said below, I'm getting an error of "cannot convert from Add to BinaryOperator".

Answer (score 0):

In your `fooKeyPressed()` do this:

```
public void divideKeyPressed() {
    _left = _value;
    _value = 0;
    _op = _dop;
}
```

The type of `_op` is of course `BinaryOperation.

Look into [Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) design pattern for generalization.

Comment: Doing that left me with an error that I can't convert from Divide to Sub?

Comment: Please edit your code in the question to show this? The member variable you assign to should NOT be of type `Sub`, it should be of type  `BinaryOperation`.

Comment: I updated the code in the question, I edited the addKeyPressed instead of the Divide in your example.

Comment: ` _aop = _op;` : you're doing it backwards. Your code needs to remember that the pressed operation (`_op`) was "add" (`_aop`). Then as you press "equals" the code will apply the current operation.

Comment: I flipped it around and I'm getting the same error. Edit: By same error I mean it is telling me that I cannot convert from Add to BinaryOperation.

Comment: Please investigate on your own. Sapienti sat.

Answer (score 0):

My error was stemming from the fact that I was importing my Add operation from part1 and my BinaryOperation from part2. By importing from part2, I fixed the error.